# How to change spacing in tailwind based on screens?

Tags: media-queries, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

How is it possible to change the spacing based on media queries?
In tailwind.config I defined my custom spacing

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      md: "768px",
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      lg: "1024px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      xl: "1280px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    },
    spacing: {
      0: "0px",
      1: "5px",
      2: "10px",
      3: "15px",
      4: "20px",
      5: "25px",
      6: "30px",
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "blue": "#243c5a",
      },
    },
    fontSize: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I know it's possible in this way:

```
<div clasname="p-1 md:p2">CONTENT</div>
```

But I want to change something like: when screen @lg p-6 to be 30, when screen @md p-6=28, when @sm=24, and so on for others spacing.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the best way to do it.
If you need to have more options you can make it like this:

```
    spacing: {
      0: "0px",
      1: "5px",
      2: "10px",
      3: "15px",
      4: "20px",
      4.5: "24px",
      5: "25px",
      5.5: "28px",
      6: "30px",
    },
```

and then use:

```
<div clasname="p-4.5 md:p-5.5 lg:p-6">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: I didn't want to make it this way, but seems like it's the only way. Thanks!